# Using Typescript compiler services to compare runtime objects with expected interfaces

Tags: typescript

At work we are just starting to convert our projects to use the `strictNullCheck` compiler setting. These are great but it is only a compile time check and shouldn't be relied upon implicitly.

For example, given the following interface for an object received from a service:

```
IContact{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
}
```

This states that none of these properties can ever be null or undefined. It is quite likely however that you may get a contact without a phone number or email so despite what this interface suggests you should indeed be checking for undefined values.

I was wondering if there was a way of checking at run time if a received object matches the interface that we defined at compile time.
The Typescript Compiler API came to mind. If we still have `d.ts` files describing the interface at run time could we use the compiler services to get a description of the interface and then write a simple library that will compare the object against this description.

Alternatively we could output some json at compile time with the information that we need about the interfaces, we would then use this at compile time instead.

I have looked at some documentation about this service but couldn't find very much.
Does anyone have any easy to follow getting started guides on this? Even a complete list of the API would be good and something that I could not find.
Has anyone done anything like this?

Thanks

Comment: Shameless plug - if your types are non-recursive, that is, no property is declared using its 'parent' or 'container' type, my [antireflection](https://github.com/fictitious/antireflection/blob/master/packages/antireflection/README.md) library might work for you (it does not use compiler services however, it just uses type inference to derive types from their descriptions, and uses these descriptions for run-time checks)

Comment: Re: "strictNullCheck is only a compile time check and shouldn't be relied upon implicitly"--actually the point of the compile-time check is to ensure that you're adding run-time checks for null.

Comment: But only if you type a variable or parameter as `string | null`. If it is just typed as `string` then no null checks are required. That is the point of this question, if you type an interface member as string rather that a possibly undefined string then TS will not prompt you to check for nulls.